# How to write select query to get all child id by parent id in mysqli

Tags: php

I am trying to get all child ids by parent id from a single table.
Below is my table `course`:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public function getLeftMenuMainCategoryInfoFromDb()
{
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT p.course_id AS parent_id ,p.course_name As parent_coursename ,c.course_id AS child_id ,c.course_name As child_coursename FROM course As p LEFT JOIN course As c ON c.course_parent_id = p.course_id WHERE p.course_parent_id = 0 ORDER BY p.course_id";
    $result = $this->selectQuery($sqlQuery);
    //print_r($result);
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(course_id),course_parent_id FROM courseGROUP BY course_parent_id`

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(course_id),course_parent_id FROM course WHERE course_parent_id =1 GROUP BY course_parent_id`

IF this is not you want please elaborate your question.

Comment: This won't ever work, as the parent and the child are allways different entries.

Answer (score 0):

I think are you looking for Parent ID should be **`GROUP BY`**

```
SELECT p.*,
       q.course_name
FROM course p
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT course_id,
          course_name
   FROM course
   WHERE course_parent_id = 0
   ORDER BY course_id) q ON p.course_parent_id = q.course_id
GROUP BY p.course_parent_id;
```